# How to get Glue Crawler to ignore partitioning

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I've got a bucket but is partitioned into dates like this:

```
s3://my-bucket/dt=2023-03-14/
s3://my-bucket/dt=2023-03-15/
```

Once a glue crawler has crawled that S3 bucket, it creates new tables named each of those dates therefore only one record in each table. How can I get crawler to stop creating new tables for each folder and instead just put it all in one folder?

Comment: The best way to structure the data for Glue to crawl against it is to have your table name in the s3 path. So something more like:

    s3://my-bucket/table_name/dt=2023-03-14/

Then you can specify table level in the glue crawler. In this case the table level would be 1, since the name of the table is the first folder level